# Is this Riemann-Integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\lfloor x\rfloor$ be the integer part function.
Let $$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} \lfloor nx\rfloor$$

Is $f(x)$ Riemann-Integrable ? Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the domain?

Comment: Boy,I'm glad I don't have to answer questions like that anymore on exams........lol

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/268128/problem-on-uniform-convergence-of-a-riemann-integrable-function) or [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243560/riemann-integrable-function) for conditions for Riemann integrability.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $[a, b]$ be a closed interval. Let's consider the Riemann integrability of $f$ on $[a, b]$.

The function $g_n(x) = \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \lfloor n x \rfloor$ is discontinuous at $\frac{1}{n} \Bbb Z$ and continuous everywhere else. It has a finite number of discontinuities on $[a, b]$. Thus, it's Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$.

Put $M = \lceil \max(|a|, |b|) \rceil$. We have:

$$
|g_n(x)| = \left| \left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^n \lfloor n x \rfloor\right| \le M \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n n
$$

Since $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n n$ converges, $f(x) = \displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n(x)$ converges uniformly by the [Weierstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test). Hence $f$ is Riemann integrable.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was very helpful.

Comment: @thetruth Happy to help!

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n} \lfloor nx\rfloor=-\frac{2x}{9}-\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\{nx\}
$$
So it is remains to show that the function 
$$
g(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{2^n}\{nx\}
$$
is Riemann integrable. Now follow the same steps presented in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/136778/19538) to conclude that $g$ is indeed Riemann integrable.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer. The problem is that I can only use the definition of Riemann-Integrable via Darboux Sums or via Jordan-Measurable arguments...

Comment: What a pity... then I need to think more on the problem. May be I'll post the solution without usage of deep techiques.

Comment: Well, I guess that the answer above just fits perfectly regarding what im allowed to use. Thanks a lot anyway :)